# Unable to have log4j write to RollingFileAppender in Grails

Tags: grails, log4j, grails-plugin, grails-2.0, rollingfileappender

I have a grails 2.3.11 plugin and application with the following log4j configuration in the Config.groovy and when I run it on the server, info and error messages do not get logged into my rollingFileAppender. When I run the application locally the messages get logged susccessfully to the console though.

myapp.log does get created under my tomcat/logs folder. However, messsages do not get written into it.

Any suggestions?

```
log4j = {

error  'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet',        // controllers
        'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages',          // GSP
        'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.sitemesh',       // layouts
        'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping.filter', // URL mapping
        'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping',        // URL mapping
        'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons',            // core / classloading
        'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins',            // plugins
        'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate',      // hibernate integration
        'org.springframework',
        'org.hibernate',
        'net.sf.ehcache.hibernate',
        'mypackage'


info   'mypackage'

appenders {

    console name:'stdout', layout:pattern(conversionPattern: '%d{ABSOLUTE} %5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n')

    appender new RollingFileAppender(
            name:"rollingFileAppender",
            maxFileSize:"1000KB",
            maxBackupIndex: 10000,
            file: "/usr/share/tomcat/logs/myapp.log",
            layout:pattern(conversionPattern: "%d %p %F:%L - %m%n")
    )
}

root{
    environments{
        development{
            info 'stdout'
        }          

        uat{
            info 'rollingFileAppender'
            error 'rollingFileAppender'
        }

        production{
            info 'rollingFileAppender'
            error 'rollingFileAppender'
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: unlikly,but try creating the initial file yourself ,and set read/write permissions to everyone

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply, I made sure that everybody had rwx (owner, group and others) but it still did not work.